# Using alternative maven module in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I currently have the following Maven setup:

Maven project A contains Maven modules b, c, d, e, f, g, h... and so on.

I have created a separate project, i.e. c1 which I need to fit into the project in the place of project c. Is there a way in eclipse or the maven framework for me to update all dependencies, and making any references to project c in overall Project A now point to c1?

I know that it will be possible to manually update the POM files and any dependencies using 'find and replace' but this seems risky and laborious. Is there any way to automate the swap out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in doing it automatically. But you could use the [MavenXpp3Reader](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html) and the [MavenXpp3Writer](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Writer.html) and code a script in Java which replaces your name.

For later changes: If you aren't sure if you want to update your names etc. later, you could create a property for that in your parent-project:

```
<properties>
    <c-Name>yourCModuleName</c-Name>
</properties>
```

Then you can use `${yourCModuleName}` in every sub-project and if you want to change it later, you'd only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Thanks, the properties and ${yourCModuleName} method is a tidy way to go forward and save time for future changes!

Comment: Also you should use that for your dependency-versions. That way you only have to change it in one place.